# Why won't I see the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, incompatibility, amsart

I tried to write table of contents to my book but encountered a problem, as it prints "Sisältö" but there is no table of contents. What is the mistake I made?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twosided,margin=3in]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.8in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\cfoot{} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-5mm}
\linespread{1.5}
\vbadness=20000
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{36pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{36pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\title{title}
\newpage
\section*{Beginning}
Some text.
\subsection*{Start}
\hspace{1em}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `section` and `subsection` rather than `section*` and `subsection*`.

Comment: I tried to use `\section` but now I got an error "! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct 
                                                  
l.24 \section{Beginning}
                        
"

Comment: `titlesec` doesn't cooperate with AMS classes.

Comment: unlike `article`. `amsart` *does* include starred headings in the table of contents.  however, this file calls `titlesec`, which redefines all of these.  gonzalo has correctly identified the problem as incompatibility between the class and the package.

Comment: Also don't use `geometry` with `amsart`...

Comment: @karlkoeller, what's problem in using `geometry` with `amsart`? other than one has to remember to specify `footskip`?

Comment: If you don't submit to the AMS, don't use `amsart` at all.

Comment: @daleif Ask Barbara Beeton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `amsart` (unlike the standard classes `book`, `report`, `article`) includes starred headings in the ToC; the problem here is that AMS classes and `titlesec` are not compatible. Even the simple document

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct 

l.6 \section{Test section}

?
```

The lesson is: *don't* use `titlesec` with AMS classes. `amsart` was tai­lored to the de­sign of Amer­i­can Math­e­mat­i­cal So­ci­ety jour­nals. If you want to modify some settings of an AMS class, you need to do it using the "AMS way"; for example, in your case, you will need to change the original definitions of `\section` and `\subsection`, and this means that you need to include the following lines in your document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

and change there the values for the spacing. Another option is just not to use AMS classes at all if you are not submitting to the AMS; switch to the standard class `article`; in this way, you can use with no problems packages such as `titlesec` to customize the sectional unit headings, or use memoir or `scrartcl` (from the KOMA bundle) which offer built-in mechanisms for customization.