# \section{} doesnt work in the \amsbook document class

Tags: amsbook

When I use the `amsbook` document class, and write down sections of chapters using `$\section{Section}$`, latex returns an error calling `\section` an 'undefined' controlled sequence. What can I do to get sections in `amsbook`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When  I use `amsbook` I get `\section{foo}` working, but don't use `$\section{foo}$` -- Why do you want to use a sectioning command in math-mode? Do you mean `\section{Foo $some math content$}` ?

Comment: Since `$\section{Section}$` is absurd, I guess that the OP was trying to use MathJax, which is not allowed here. Without other details, the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Both `amsbook.cls` as `article.cls` use the `\par` code in `\@startsection`, this isn't allowed in mathmode, that's why `$\section{foo}$` must fail.

Comment: wait for the OP to come back but I'd guess the `$` was a mistake in the site wiki markup using `$` instead of `\` ` rather than something in the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's true, but nevertheless my answer isn't wrong, is it?

Comment: @Zarko: Really? ;-)

Comment: yes it's wrong really since the question says there is an undefined control sequence error. I would guess that the actual problem is `\section{\zhagagafa}` and `\section` is just reported as the location, but teh undefined command is `\zhagagafa`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True -- I've answered another wrong feature of the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`amsbook` defines `\section` so that is not the problem.

I would guess that your document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}

\section{zzzz a\xyz\ hhh}

zzzz

\end{document}
```

which produces a message on the terminal like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> zzzz a\xyz 
                      \ hhh
l.5 \section{zzzz a\xyz\ hhh}

?
```

this does not say that `\section` is undefined, the last line of a TeX error message shows the location in the source so here `l.5` line 5 `\section{zzzz a\xyz\ hhh}`

The important part of the error message is the first line which is always split over two lines with the linebreak showing the point at which TeX stopped reading and issued the error.

So for an undefined control sequence error the control sequence that is undefined is always the last token on the first line of the message after the `!...` line.  Here `\xyz`.

The solution is to define that command, but it depends what the command is, for which we need to see the full error message as above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158554/why-wont-i-see-the-table-of-contents) that AMS classes and titlesec are not compatible.